# Stamp duty liability when adding partner to mortgage? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, tax-law

My friend and her partner have recently moved in together (England). Her partner owns a property that is now being let out, and she has added him to her mortgage.

They were under the impression he would be liable to pay Stamp Duty as he now owns a second property, however the solicitor has told them he doesn't need to pay it.

Is this classed differently as he has been added to the mortgage and not "purchased" a property together?

Comment: What does the solicitor say?

Comment: Never gave a reason why they didn't need to pay just said they didn't.

Comment: He owns 100% of his existing property and now owns 50% of their current property due to transfer of ownership and being added onto her existing mortgage.

Comment: Well, if the solicitor says so who are we to say otherwise

Comment: There may be a difference being "added to the mortgage" as somebody liable to pay, and being added to the registered ownership (either as a 'joint tenant' or as a 'tenant in common').

Answer (score 1):

Web search for "stamp duty" ownership change.

First result:

> [Stamp Duty Land Tax: transfer ownership of land or property](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/sdlt-transferring-ownership-of-land-or-property#if-you-marry-enter-into-a-civil-partnership-or-set-up-home-together)
>
> You may need to pay [Stamp Duty Land Tax](https://www.gov.uk/stamp-duty-land-tax) when all or part of an interest in land or property is transferred to you and you give anything of monetary value in exchange.
>
> Anything of monetary value that you give in exchange is called the ‘chargeable consideration’.
>
> The rules you use to work out how much Stamp Duty Land Tax you pay depend on the circumstances of the property transfer. ...

If the partner takes liability for the mortgage, the partner will have 'chargeable consideration' for their share of the property.

For example (summarising from that page) the partner takes on 50% of a £600,000 mortgage. So £300,000 is the 'chargeable consideration' for the share of the property. Current SDLT threshold for residential property is £250,000. Partner pays 0% x £250,000 + 5% x £50,000 = £2,500.

If on the other hand the partner's chargeable consideration is less than the SDLT threshold there is no tax to pay but "you must still tell HMRC about the transaction on an Stamp Duty Land Tax return".